# pasar valores por ajax error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo una rutina para actualizar es estado y el saldo de un documento, este es el codigo jquery

```
$("#invBtnPay").on("click", function (event) {
        alertify.confirm("Pagar Factura", "El Saldo de la Factura es de $" + $("#idt_saldo").text(),
            function () {
                var invoiceStatus = {
                    'inv_id': $("#inv_id").val(),
                    'inv_status': "Pagada",
                    'inv_pay': $("#idt_saldo").text(),
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: './core/invoiceStatus.php',
                    data: invoiceStatus,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    encode: true
                })
                    .done(function (invoiceStatus) {
                        if (invoiceStatus.success) {
                            $('#inv_status').addClass('badge badge-warning');
                            $('#inv_status').text(invoiceStatus.status);
                            window.location.href = "account.php?page=adm_add_invoice&title=Facturacion";
                        }
                        else {
                            alertify.error(invoiceStatus.message);
                        }
                    });
            },
            function () {
                alertify.warning('Accion Cancelada!');
            }).set('labels', { ok: 'Hacer el Pago', cancel: 'Cancelar' });
```

y este es el codigo php

```
<?php
    require_once("../config.php");

    $inv_id = $_POST['inv_id'];
    $inv_status = $_POST['inv_status'];
    $inv_pay = (!isset($_POST['inv_pay']) ? 0 : $_POST['inv_pay']); //toma el valor y lo divide entre 1000

    $update = "UPDATE doc_master SET balance = balance - ?, status = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($update);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $inv_pay, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $inv_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $inv_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute();

    $invoiceStatus = []; 

    if($update){
        $invoiceStatus ['success'] = true;
        $invoiceStatus ['invoiceId'] = $inv_id;
        $invoiceStatus ['message'] = "Factura ".$inv_status." con Exito!";
        $invoiceStatus ['status'] = $inv_status;
        echo json_encode($invoiceStatus);
    }
    else
    {
        $invoiceStatus ['success'] = false;
        $invoiceStatus ['message'] = "Algo salio mal, No fue posible actualizar en estado de la Factura!";
        echo json_encode($invoiceStatus);
    }
?>
```

Como ven, envío el id del documento `($inv_id)`, el nuevo estado `($inv_status)` y el valor a descontar `($inv_pay)` y en este es donde esta el problema, sucede que se envía el valor 5,300.00 y a php llega 5.3 y este es valor que descuenta del total del documento de tal manera que el saldo queda en 5,294.70

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen se ve como quedan los valores después del pago

Como puedo solucionar este inconveniente?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Revisa primero que estas enviando, cual es el valor inv_pay antes de enviar con un `console.log` para saber si el problema es de javascript o de php

Comment: Si, en el `alertify.confirm` muestro el valor a enviar.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor que envías? @JuanCarlos? ahora hace un `var_dump`  en el php a la variable y después de que haces la transformación a entero, en `$inv_id, PDO::PARAM_INT`

Comment: Hice el `var_dump($inv_pay);` a la variable y el valor que muestra es `\InvoiceStatus.php:8:string '7.50000' (length=7)` lo que indica que el valor se envia bien pero llega mal, el valor de `$_POST['inv_pay']` es el mismo...

Comment: le quite el `replace` sugerido por @Einer y el resultado cambio a ... `InvoiceStatus.php:8:string '3.200,00' (length=8)` lo que indica que los separadores de miles y decimales estan mal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que recibís en el servidor es un string y podés convertir este valor a un float y después realizar la resta. Para hacer la conversión tenés la función [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php). En la página de la documentación tenés otra función para considerar el separador de miles(entre otras cosas):

```
function tofloat($num) {
    $dotPos = strrpos($num, '.');
    $commaPos = strrpos($num, ',');
    $sep = (($dotPos > $commaPos) && $dotPos) ? $dotPos : 
        ((($commaPos > $dotPos) && $commaPos) ? $commaPos : false);

    if (!$sep) {
        return floatval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $num));
    } 

    return floatval(
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, 0, $sep)) . '.' .
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, $sep+1, strlen($num)))
    );
}

$num = '1.999,369€';
var_dump(tofloat($num)); // float(1999.369)
$otherNum = '126,564,789.33 m²';
var_dump(tofloat($otherNum)); // float(126564789.33)
////Con tus valores:
$num='5,325.23';
var_dump(tofloat($num)); // float(5325.23)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/NW4e9hQH)(de la página de documentación que te dejé):

Después podés tomar ese valor y restar en la base de datos.

Comment: gracias a todos por sus aportes, realmente lo que hay que hacer es darle el formato correcto a los valores, esa era la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Php lee el valor 5,300 como: **Cinco punto 3**, no Cinco mil trescientos. Esto porque estas enviando el separador decimal despues del cinco. Si quieres que te funciones tendra que eliminar el separador para que php lo interprete como cinco mil trescientos.

En ves de enviar: `5,300.00`. debes de enviar `5300.00`.

Intenta con esto:

```
//..

var invoiceStatus = {
 'inv_id': $("#inv_id").val(),
 'inv_status': "Pagada",
 'inv_pay': $("#idt_saldo").text().replace(',',''), //<-- eliminas el separador , del monto enviado
};

//...
```

Comment: Nada, no es la solución, gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Puedes confirmar que se este eliminando el separador? Puedes mostrarme el valor exacto que esta llegando al servidor?

Comment: edite la pregunta con una imagen para mostrar como quedan los valores después del pago, `inv_total` es el total del documento y `inv_balance` es el saldo después del pago, yo estoy enviado pagos totales...